# Bit masking java, only showing last 6 bites of a hex

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I am playing around on how to manipulate bytes from an inputted Hex number. Data is a Hex:
0x022DA822 == 10001011011010100000100010. After I run the following code:

```
    byte mask= (byte) data;
```

mask will =    100010, only those last bits. How come it only shows the last 6 bits or 22 in the hex?

Does it mask the first 20 bits by default?

Comment: What is the decimal representation of `0x022DA822`?

Comment: 36546594 =decimal representation

Comment: What is the data range of `byte`?

Comment: what do you mean data range?

Comment: What is the minimum value a `byte` can represent? What is the maximum value a `byte` can represent?

Comment: isnt it 127 to -127 or something

Comment: [-128 to 127](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). How do you store `36546594` in something like that?

Comment: Ok, I get your drift, I was experimenting with a For Loop using << and I was getting negative numbers, but none below -128. 100010 was in the range while 100000100010 wasnt. Am I on the right track?

Comment: You are. A `byte` is 8 bits. Your value `0x022DA822` needs at least an `int` (32 bits) for representation. There's a conversion from `int` to `byte` which happens during a cast.

Comment: Ok, I got it now. I am using an Int based mask, then >>> 6 spots to remove last 6 bits and focus on next bits. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cast is causing a loss of data. A byte can hold (you guessed it), one byte of data. Thus the range of a byte is [-128, 127]. Note that the most significant bit is reserved as the sign bit. So basically when you are saying: (byte)data, you are converting your hex data into a variable of type byte, which has a smaller range than your hex string. And thus only the last byte of your data can be stored in the byte.